# Create a simple 2 panel graph in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to make two panel graph in  LaTeX. I don't know how complex it will be. Can anyone suggest what would be the starting point in creating such graphs ?

The graph is as follows:

[image]

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Do you need just these two, or are you going to be drawing lots of different graphs of this type?

Comment: @ Jake : Thank you for your response. I may need to add some more of this type.

Comment: Alright, so that would require a solution that's automated in some way. Could you edit your question to explain in a bit more detail what the "specifications" of these graphs are? For example, what do the boxes represent? Do they have to have a certain width, does the width ever change? Do the line graphs always go up to the same height?

Comment: Hi Jake, they don't have specific lengths and widths. The lines can be approximate. They don't have to be exact. On the first figure, the hatched block on the top will extend up to the top vertex of the triangle. In the bottom figure, the hatched block extend to the second vertex of the trapezoid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

The `CAD` module of the `Asymptote` package can help. The following
`p.tex` will generate a `panel.asy` file, which has a brief sketch
of a class (struct) `Panel`, it has a simple structure and can be 
easily customized further, if necessary. See the `operator init` for details.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{panel.asy}
import CAD;

struct Panel{
  real Tc, QpR, D;
  real blockHeight, blockTop; 
  int nSections;
  real xtipSize,ytipSize;
  sCAD cad;
  void drawGraph(){
    draw(g=(0,0)*cm--(Tc,QpR)*cm--(D,QpR)*cm--(D+Tc,0)*cm,cad.pA);
    draw(g=(D+Tc,0)*cm--(D+Tc,QpR)*cm,cad.pB);
    cad.MeasureParallel(L = "$Q_{pR}$",
      pFrom = (Tc, 0)*cm,
      pTo = (Tc, QpR)*cm,
      dblDistance = 0mm);
    cad.MeasureParallel(L = "$T_{c}$",
      pFrom = (0, QpR)*cm,
      pTo = (Tc, QpR)*cm,
      dblDistance = 2mm);
    cad.MeasureParallel(L = "$T_{c}$",
      pFrom = (D, QpR)*cm,
      pTo = (D+Tc, QpR)*cm,
      dblDistance = 2mm);    
  }

  void drawBlock(){
    real dx=D/nSections;
    for(int i=1;i<nSections;++i){
      draw(((i*dx, blockTop-blockHeight)*cm--(i*dx, blockTop)*cm),cad.pB);
    }
    draw(box((0, blockTop-blockHeight)*cm, (D, blockTop)*cm),cad.pA);

    cad.MeasureParallel(L = "$D$",
      pFrom = (0, blockTop)*cm,
      pTo = (D, blockTop)*cm,
      dblDistance = 2mm);
  }
  void drawAxes(){
    draw((0,0)*cm--(D+Tc+xtipSize,0)*cm,cad.pB,Arrow(HookHead,size=1mm));
    draw((0,0)*cm--(0,blockTop+1+ytipSize)*cm,cad.pB,Arrow(HookHead,size=1mm));
  }

  void drawYLabel(){
    label(rotate(90)*Label("Discharges (cms)")
    ,0.5(0,blockTop+1+ytipSize)*cm
    ,W);
  }

  void operator init(real Tc, real QpR, real D=Tc
    , real blockHeight=0.5, real blockTop=1.5QpR, int nSections=10
    ,real xtipSize=0.5, real ytipSize=xtipSize){
    this.Tc=Tc;
    this.QpR=QpR;
    this.D=D;
    this.blockHeight=blockHeight;
    this.blockTop=blockTop;
    this.nSections=nSections;
    this.xtipSize=xtipSize;
    this.ytipSize=ytipSize;
    this.cad = sCAD.Create();
    drawGraph();
    drawBlock();
    drawAxes();
    drawYLabel();
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
%
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{asy}
size(7cm);
import panel;
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
Panel pan=Panel(3, 4,nSections=11);
\end{asy}
%
\caption{$D=T_c$}
\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{asy}
size(8cm);
import panel;
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
Panel pan=Panel(2, 5,D=6,nSections=15);
\end{asy}
%
\caption{$D>T_c$}
\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:

```
sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

and run `latexmk -pdf p.tex`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a possibility using TikZ; some auxiliary commands were defined to automate the drawing of some elements of the diagrams (see explanation below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows}

\newcommand\textarrow[3]{%
  \draw[<->,] #1 -- node[fill=white] {$\scriptstyle #3$} #2;}

\newcommand\myrect[3]{%
\begin{scope}[
  yshift=#2,
  start chain,
  every node/.style={on chain,inner sep=0pt,text width=2mm},
  node distance=-\pgflinewidth,anchor=west
]
\foreach \mvalue  in {1,...,\the\numexpr#1*5\relax}
   \node[draw,text height=14pt] {};
\end{scope}
\draw[<->] 
  ([yshift=#2+19pt]0,0) -- 
    node[fill=white] {$\scriptstyle#3$} 
  ([yshift=#2+19pt]#1,0);
\draw ([yshift=#2+9pt]#1,0) -- +(0,15pt);
}

\newcommand\axes[2]{%
\draw[->] (0,0) -- +(0,#1);
\draw[->] (0,0) -- +(#2,0);
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\axes{7}{7}
\draw (0,0) -- (3,4) -- (6,0);
\textarrow{(3,0)}{(3,4)}{Q_pR}
\textarrow{(0,-12pt)}{(3,-12pt)}{r_c}
\textarrow{(3,-12pt)}{(6,-12pt)}{r_c}
\foreach \xcoor in {0,3,6}
  \draw (\xcoor,-2pt) -- +(0,-15pt);
\myrect{3}{5.25cm}{D-T_c}
\node[rotate=90,anchor=south,font=\small] at (0,3) {Discharge (cms)};
\node[anchor=east,font=\small] at (0,5.2) {(A)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\axes{7}{9}
\draw (0,0) -- (2,4) -- (6,4) -- (8,0);
\textarrow{(2,0)}{(2,4)}{Q_pR}
\textarrow{(0,4cm+12pt)}{(2,4cm+12pt)}{r_c}
\textarrow{(6,4cm+12pt)}{(8,4cm+12pt)}{r_c}
\foreach \xcoor in {2,6}
  \draw (\xcoor,4cm+2pt) -- +(0,15pt);
\draw (8,0) -- +(0,4cm+17pt);
\myrect{6}{5.5cm}{D}
\node[rotate=90,anchor=south,font=\small] at (0,3) {Discharge (cms)};
\node[anchor=east,font=\small] at (0,5.5) {(B)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The auxiliary commands are:

```
\axes{<length1>}{<length2>}
```

draws two perpendicular axes: from `(0,0)` to `(0,<lenght1>)` and from `(0,0)` to `(<length2>,0)`.

```
\myrect{<value>}{<length>}{<text>}
```

draws the hatched rectangle starting at `(0,<length>)` and going to the right a distance equal to `<value>`; it also places an arrow on top of the rectangle with `<text>` in the middle. In its current form, `<value>` has to be a positive integer.

Finally, the third command

```
\textarrow{<pos1>}{<pos2>}{<text>}
```

draws a line between `<pos1>` and `<pos2>` with arrow tips on both ends and with `<text>` in the middle. For example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\axes{5}{12}
\myrect{3}{3cm}{a}
\myrect{6}{1cm}{b}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image]

and

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\textarrow{(3.5,0)}{(3.5,3)}{a}
\textarrow{(0,0)}{(3,0)}{b}
\textarrow{(4,0)}{(6,3)}{c}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That is very detailed. I will start to create figures now based on your wonderful answer.